# Creating time categories and adding them to dataset

Tags: time

I've been trying tirelessly to figure out this issue and I cannot seem to make it work...
I am working on a project comparing activity times of some mammalian species and need to run a multinomial model in the nnet package. To do this, I need to convert the timestamp data I have into categories of time. So far, I have tried to use the which() function, strptime, strftime, and some others that I've had little luck with. I have the data both in date and time format, just time format, and just hour format in my csv and cannot figure out how to categorize time with any of these. I'd like to add these categories to my dataset as well so I can see which species were active during which times.
The times I'd like to classify are as follows:
Nocturnal: 10pm-4am
Crepuscular: 4am-8am; 6pm-10pm
Diurnal: 8am-6pm

Any help would be so greatly appreciated!!!!!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please show use what code you do have, as well as tagging the programming language in question. You can edit your questions with the edit button usually located below the question.

Comment: You can use single backticks for code blocks that look like: `this`. You can use triple backticks for multi like code blocks.